# Getting error after using ErrorAction Silentlcontinue in my command

Tags: powershell

I am still getting error in my out after using `-Erroraction Silentcontinue`. Here is my command I am using:

```
 get-childitem c:\ -include *.bak -recurse | foreach ($_) {remove-item $_.fullname } -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable a
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably retrieve the error within the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet. So you should add the parameter there too (`-ea 0` is the alias for `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`).

Also the usage of the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet within your code is obsolete since the `Remove-Item` cmdlet takes a pipeline object:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\ -include *.bak -recurse -ea 0 |  Remove-Item -ea 0
```

Comment: Can we print something after this command executes in same  command line?

Comment: what do you want to print?

Comment: i just want to print like "Cleanup Success" but in same command line

Comment: Just use the write-host cmdlet?